# Analyse disk usage for root partition excluding other partitions that are mounted with GUI program?

Tags: disk-usage

I want to check my file usage with programs like https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Festplattenbelegung/ for the files on my partitions on which `/` (root) is on. However, there are many other files systems mounted into the file system somewhere. Those I do not want to check out - only my root partition. How can I exclude those? I would like to use a GUI program (so not `du`). I thought that I either find a program in which can do the exclusion, but I haven't found one. I thought another option might be if I could mount my root device (`/dev/mapper/mylvg-myrootpartition`) to another location *additionally* to the normal mount to `/` and analyse this second mount folder, but I haven't managed to do that. Ideas?

Answer (score 42):

There are gui tools, but give ncdu a try. It's a cli tool, fast and allows you to navigate directories whilst easily viewing the usage % of each dir.

```
ncdu -x /
```

The `-x` option stands for

> Do not cross filesystem boundaries, i.e. only count files and directories on the same filesystem as the directory being scanned.

If it really must be an X gui tool, I found the source code of that unix interface from Jurassic Park a while ago, was good for a laugh... will try to find...

Comment: here is that Jurassic Park one: git@github.com:mcuelenaere/fsv.git

Comment: `ncdu` does the trick!

Comment: This answer was _exactly_ what I was looking for.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 5):

[GNOME's Disk Usage Analyzer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Baobab) (also known as Baobab) limits itself to single filesystems: thus, asking it to analyse `/` won't include `/home` if that's a separate filesystem, or `/proc`, `/sys` etc.

When you explicitly open a folder for analysis in Baobab, there's a check-box you can use to toggle that behaviour:

[image: "Recursively analyze mount points"]

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case for me, whether I select my home directory normally, or explicitly open my home directory with "recursively analyze mount points" deselected, Baobab still tries to recurse down into every single `.snapshot` folder, each one being it's own separate mount point.